# Minikube exiting due to RSRC_OVER_ALLOC_MEM

Tags: docker, kubernetes, memory, minikube

I'm trying to start a minikube cluster using:

```
minikube start --memory='16g'
```

but keep getting an error:

```
❌  Exiting due to RSRC_OVER_ALLOC_MEM: Requested memory allocation 16384MB is more than your system limit 7956MB.
  Suggestion: Start minikube with less memory allocated: 'minikube start --memory=2200mb'
```

I just updated my RAM from 16Gb to 32Gb, and was wondering if there's a way for me to bypass this problem and increase the system limit.

Tried to search this error online but didnt find anything useful.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt mention me working through WSL.
the reason I got this error was because I edited `~/.wslconfig` to allow only 12gb of memory.

editing the file solved the problem - upgrading the memory itself wont change the values in the file!